# Can sonarlint be used in place of checkstyle?

Tags: java, static-analysis, checkstyle, pmd, sonarlint

I am working on a project which already has sonarqube integrated. Now, we want to have a plugin in our local IDE(with some sort of XML) so that everyone in the team can have the same set of rules.

I see two options :

- **SonarLint**:  I read that SonarQube already has rules that are a replacement of what checkstyle/pmd and other analyzers have.

> So if I use sonarlint and connect it with our sonarqube server, will sonarlint be able to identify all the checkstyle/PMD violations on our IDE or we will miss some important violations provided by these external analyzers?

- **Checkstyle**/**PMD**: We can have different plugins for each of these analyzers with their XML file that can be shared with team. But this way, we won't be able to integrate with sonarqube.

What would be the better approach?

Comment: I was hoping someone would answer as I'd be interested in it myself. I would suggest that you initially use Sonarlint _in addition_ to Checkstyle/PMD. You'll get annoying duplicate warnings because they'll flag many of the same issues, but you'll see how you get on and be able to decide whether Sonarlint is a suitable replacement.

Comment: Thanks! going by this approach for now.